# A way to send 1 email once done reading from CSV

Tags: python, email

I wrote a script to send an email if the values match a certain criteria. I'm wanting to send 1 email instead of multiple emails upon every check. I thought I can mitigate by throwing in another function but I can't figure out how to do it. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

```
import csv, requests, xmltodict, smtplib, email.utils
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def sendEmail(host, value, devicename):
    # Create the message
    msg = MIMEText('This is the body of the message.')
        msg['To'] = email.utils.formataddr(('Recipient', 'XXXXXX'))
        msg['From'] = email.utils.formataddr(('Author', 'XXXXX'))
        msg['Subject'] = 'Simple test message'
        server = smtplib.SMTP('XXXXXXX')
        server.set_debuglevel(True) # show communication with the server

    try:
        server.sendmail('XXXXXX', ['XXXXXX'], msg.as_string())
    finally:
        server.quit()

def check(hostIP, value):
    xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>"""

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}
    response = requests.post('http://' + hostIP + '/RPC2', data=xml, headers=headers).text

    doc = xmltodict.parse(response)
    uptime = str(doc['response'])

    maxtime = '300'
    time = str(uptimeValue)
    day = time // (24 * 3600)

    if day >= maxtime:
        print 'it is'
        sendEmail(str(hostIP), str(value), str(devicename))
    else:
        print "it is not!"

def main():
    try:
        with open('list.csv', 'r') as file:
            reader = csv.DictReader(file)
            for row in reader:
                check(row['Host'], row['Value'])
    except Exception as error:
        print ValueError("Could not properly read the csv file")
        sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: Will the 1 email contain all of the information now split up over multiple email messages?

Comment: There is no `mail data`, you are sending a **empty** mail.

Comment: @ScottHunter - Yeah, I want the 1 email to contain all the data. Right now when I run the script, it sends 1 email per loop

Comment: @stovfl - Yeah. it's that way since I'm still testing. I want it to basically just aggregate all the data and send 1 email instead of multiple. In testing I get "This is the body of the message." 10 times with the number of devices I'm testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
def sendEmail(message):
```

and

```
    if day >= maxtime:
        print 'it is'
        return (str(hostIP), str(value), str(devicename))
```

and

```
device_list = []
for row in reader:
    result = check(row['Host'], row['Value'])
    if result:
        device_list.append(', '.join(result))

sendEmail('\n'.join(device_list))
```

Comment: that actually worked!! But now I'm facing a problem with the functions if the day is less than the max time. It used to work but now it just breaks the loop. I put a return and then a pass after the else statement and that didn't help. Anything else I can put?

Comment: Basically it just doesn't go through the loop again.

Comment: I did not know that can be done! and that makes sense now. That worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `check` to send the email, use it to add an item to go into the message body, probably in an array or dictionary.  Then, after you are done processing your file, you can use that collected information to build the body of your email to give to a single call to `sendEmail`.

That means you don't call `sendEmail` from inside of `check`; you call it from `main` once you are done with the file.

Comment: So, now the question is...how do I have check wait until its done processing the csv before sending everything to the sendEmail function? I think that is the biggest thing I'm drawing a blank to.